# How to use bcp utility with oracle dB or any other better options

Tags: oracle, bulkinsert, bcp

I have a csv file which has to be bulk imported to oracle dB. I was working on other sybase dB engine before so I had a sample script which has the environment setup for it. Right now I have to do the process in a oracle dB so what should be the first line I know about the rest other parameters but want to know the path which has to be defined when I write 
`path/bcp dbtable in data.txt`
If anyone could help what should be the path for oracle dB

Comment: Oracle doesn't have BCP. Here are some other options https://sqlandplsql.com/2017/02/16/5-different-ways-to-load-flat-file-into-oracle-table/

Answer (score 4):

The primary tools for bulk or flat file loading are:

1. [SQL*Loader](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-administration/oracle-sqlloader/)
2. [External Tables](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-administration/oracle-external-table/) ([and here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/external-tables-9i))
3. GUI Tools like [SQL*Developer](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-7068681A-DC4C-4E09-AC95-6A5590203818.htm#ADMQS0826)

It is much more cumbersome, but if necessary you can roll your own solution with the [UTL_FILE](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=utl-file-to-read-csv) PL/SQL package.