# handle huge list of insert statement

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, liquibase

I have a huge list of insert statements in a file as shown below, I need to use stored procedure or liquibase script to execute these statement in production database. If any of the record(s) gets failed to insert then everything should be rolled back. Also performance is important here.

```
insert into employee (empid, empname, slary) values (1, 'bar', 2000);
insert into employee (empid, empname, slary) values (2, 'foo', 2000);
.
.
insert into employee (empid, empname, slary) values (100000, 'baz', 2000);
```

Comment: You may want to look into [Oracle's Direct Path](https://danischnider.wordpress.com/2018/02/20/direct-path-insert-and-nologging-with-oracle-12-2/) to load this data. If you are actually loading each row with an insert you will need to create a staging table then do a [select /*+ append */ ...](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/append-hint).

Answer (score 3):

Insert 100 rows-at-a-time using the `UNION ALL` trick and wrap the entire code with a `BEGIN` and `END`. This is a little trickier to generate than a simple list of inserts, but batching the operations reduces the row-by-row overhead and usually improves performance by around 10x.

```
begin
    insert into employee (empid, empname, slary)
        select 1, 'bar', 2000 from dual union all
        select 2, 'foo', 2000 from dual union all
        ...
        select 100, 'foobar', 2000 from dual;

    ...

    insert into employee (empid, empname, slary)
        ...
        select 100000, 'baz', 2000 from dual;
end;
/
```

I use 100 rows because if you batch *all* of the rows into a single `INSERT` Oracle may take too long to parse the enormous SQL statement. Using the `BEGIN` and `END` has Oracle pass the entire block at once over the network, and also ensures that a single failure in one statement will rollback everything else.

You don't need direct path, `/*+ append */` hints, dropping and recreating indexes, locking, SQL Loader, or any of those fancy features. Those are good ideas for a huge amount of *data*. But you've actually got a *small* amount of data, just a *huge* number of statements. You need to optimize for network lag and SQL parsing - the actual time to load the data is likely irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it with simple plsql block. For example:

```
begin
   -- all your inserts go here without any changes
   insert into employee (empid, empname, slary) values (1, 'bar', 2000);
   insert into employee (empid, empname, slary) values (2, 'foo', 2000);
   .
   .
   insert into employee (empid, empname, slary) values (100000, 'baz', 2000);

   --commit once in the end
   commit;
end;
```

This way if anything will fail - the whole transaction(which includes all inserts) will be rolled back automatically.

From perfromance point of view, you will save time on newwork roundtrips, since there will be only 1 call to the db with all the inserts inside. The performance will not be the best though. Plain inserts are not the fastest way to load data in database. Use sqlldr(external utility) for bulk load and best performance.

Answer (score 0):

To improve performance:

- Disable or drop any indexes and constraints on the `employees` table.  You can recreate them afterwards.

  - **Note**:  this could be dangerous if your data is not sorted.  Putting back an index could take a long time.
- Lock the table when inserting
- Insert in batches
- Check out the [Oracle](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-administration/oracle-sqlloader/) utility for bulk operations

  - See [How to use bcp utility with oracle dB or any other better options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62129044/how-to-use-bcp-utility-with-oracle-db-or-any-other-better-options) for other utilities

For rollbacks, you can use the [ROLLBACK](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/rollback_statement.htm) transaction